# How To Display Current Login User Data On His User Dashboard From Database

Tags: php, database, authentication, session

This code show current login username

`<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>`

As like above code I want to show other user details as. 
How code for it? Please tell me example code for "age, birthday, etc..."

Comment: This is too broad a question. Surely there are tutorials out on the Web for this. Have you searched for and tried anything? Plus, seeing this db-related, the RDBMS used would probably be useful.

Comment: _“How code for it?”_ - well, basically the exact same way, as with the user name …? That must find its way _into_ the session at some point, so … add the additional data you want to store into your session at that point then …?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a session with: session_start() and then set the values ​​you want as follows:

```
$_SESSION["username"]=$value;
$_SESSION["birthday"]=$value;
$_SESSION["age"]=$value;
```

And to redeem the values

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['birthday'];?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['age'];?>
```

See more here: 
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['example'] =$value;
echo $_SESSION['example'];
?>` it not work